# Firefox speedport.ip webpage not found

Tags: router, firefox, wireless-router, http, wireless-access-point

I've the following problem, I installed an *Telekom Speedport Router* as access point via LAN in my current network. It is connected to my first *FritzBox Router*. In the settings of my *Telekom Speedport Router*, I disabled DHCP and assigned a static IP address. Everything works great I've internet access!

My problem is know that it's not possible to access the webpage (http://speedport.ip) of my *Telekom Speedport Router*! Firefox returns the following error message: `We can’t connect to the server at www.speedport.ip`, after I typed `speedport.ip`!

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/584305/firefox-says-server-not-found-because-its-adding-www-how-do-i-stop-this) but the answer doesn't solve the problem!

Firefox-Version: 60.0.1 (64-Bit) Ubuntu

IP-Speedport: 192.168.179.5

IP-FritzBox: 192.168.179.1

It is interesting, if I connect with a telnet client, the port 80 is definitely open, and I modify the request header than it works, I receive HTML content, but only if I modify the host to `speedport.ip`

```
$ telnet 192.168.179.5 80
Trying 192.168.179.5...
Connected to 192.168.179.5.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /login.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: speedport.ip
```

Any ideas how to access the router webpage via Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you’re using the Speedport as your actual Internet gateway, the “domain highjacking” cannot work. It relies on the fact that your network devices use the device’s DNS forwarder. So on your network, you can only use `fritz.box`.

I haven’t heard of any routers that require a specific `Host` header. However, you can easily check that by adding an entry for `speedport.ip` to your computer’s `hosts` file:

```
192.168.179.5 speedport.ip
```

The hosts file is located at `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows and at `/etc/hosts` on most other operating systems. It requires Admin/root to edit.

Comment: Thank you a lot it works like a charm! But I'm interested in what was the problem?

Comment: I don’t know, maybe try the Telekom help forum. Maybe a Telekom employee will trigger a review process of the router’s firmware. Like I said: A router should not require any specific `Host` header value. It doesn’t do name-based virtual hosting, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good bet would be to actually type in 192.168.179.5, this should open up the webpage of your speedport router.

Comment: I actully tried this it doesn't work! I don't know if the reson for thid could be that the FritzBlx settings block access at external webpages via IP?

Comment: I know for a fact that fritzbox doesn't block internal web pages. Have you tried checking if your IP subnets match? 

Judging from your ip range it should be: 255.255.255.0

Comment: Yea of course I checked it! Everything seems to be correct...

Comment: Very odd indeed....